# Javascript JSON response from Flickr parse error

Tags: javascript, json, flickr

i have a missunderstanding on how to parse the json from Flickr because it has a named function in front of json like this ( **I used .replace() to format it like this** )

```
jsonFlickrFeed({
        "title": "Uploads from everyone",
        "link": "https://www.flickr.com/photos/",
        "description": "",
        "modified": "2017-06-14T08:08:45Z",
        "generator": "https://www.flickr.com",
        "items": [
       {
            "title": "PICT5162",
            "link": "https://www.flickr.com/photos/57727182@N08/34455881614/",
            "media": {"m":"https://farm5.staticflickr.com/4252/34455881614_c488502d97_m.jpg"},
            "date_taken": "2011-01-01T08:20:44-08:00",
            "description": " <p><a href="https://www.flickr.com/people/57727182@N08/">bobbyblack51</a> posted a photo:</p> <p><a href="https://www.flickr.com/photos/57727182@N08/34455881614/" title="PICT5162"><img src="https://farm5.staticflickr.com/4252/34455881614_c488502d97_m.jpg" width="240" height="160" alt="PICT5162" /></a></p> ",
            "published": "2017-06-14T08:08:45Z",
            "author": "nobody@flickr.com ("bobbyblack51")",
            "author_id": "57727182@N08",
            "tags": ""
       },
       {
            "title": "Chup len mong",
            "link": "https://www.flickr.com/photos/151619623@N04/34455882074/",
            "media": {"m":"https://farm5.staticflickr.com/4250/34455882074_4cc00653c2_m.jpg"},
            "date_taken": "2017-06-12T09:10:58-08:00",
            "description": " <p><a href="https://www.flickr.com/people/151619623@N04/">huynhtri1</a> posted a photo:</p> <p><a href="https://www.flickr.com/photos/151619623@N04/34455882074/" title="Chup len mong"><img src="https://farm5.staticflickr.com/4250/34455882074_4cc00653c2_m.jpg" width="180" height="240" alt="Chup len mong" /></a></p> ",
            "published": "2017-06-14T08:08:46Z",
            "author": "nobody@flickr.com ("huynhtri1")",
            "author_id": "151619623@N04",
            "tags": ""
       },
```

and this is the actual true response from Flickr :

```
jsonFlickrFeed({
        "title": "Uploads from everyone",
        "link": "https:\/\/www.flickr.com\/photos\/",
        "description": "",
        "modified": "2017-06-14T08:13:53Z",
        "generator": "https:\/\/www.flickr.com",
        "items": [
       {
            "title": " ",
            "link": "https:\/\/www.flickr.com\/photos\/155707338@N06\/34455957324\/",
            "media": {"m":"https:\/\/farm5.staticflickr.com\/4266\/34455957324_c1657846cb_m.jpg"},
            "date_taken": "2017-05-31T13:57:23-08:00",
            "description": " <p><a href=\"https:\/\/www.flickr.com\/people\/155707338@N06\/\">gulicolam<\/a> posted a photo:<\/p> <p><a href=\"https:\/\/www.flickr.com\/photos\/155707338@N06\/34455957324\/\" title=\" \"><img src=\"https:\/\/farm5.staticflickr.com\/4266\/34455957324_c1657846cb_m.jpg\" width=\"240\" height=\"180\" alt=\" \" \/><\/a><\/p> ",
            "published": "2017-06-14T08:13:53Z",
            "author": "nobody@flickr.com (\"gulicolam\")",
            "author_id": "155707338@N06",
            "tags": ""
       },
       {
            "title": "My specs",
            "link": "https:\/\/www.flickr.com\/photos\/133444761@N05\/34489902583\/",
            "media": {"m":"https:\/\/farm5.staticflickr.com\/4266\/34489902583_b84ce9132a_m.jpg"},
            "date_taken": "2017-06-14T09:12:50-08:00",
            "description": " <p><a href=\"https:\/\/www.flickr.com\/people\/133444761@N05\/\">sabre aviation<\/a> posted a photo:<\/p> <p><a href=\"https:\/\/www.flickr.com\/photos\/133444761@N05\/34489902583\/\" title=\"My specs\"><img src=\"https:\/\/farm5.staticflickr.com\/4266\/34489902583_b84ce9132a_m.jpg\" width=\"240\" height=\"180\" alt=\"My specs\" \/><\/a><\/p> <p>cof<\/p>",
            "published": "2017-06-14T08:13:47Z",
            "author": "nobody@flickr.com (\"sabre aviation\")",
            "author_id": "133444761@N05",
            "tags": ""
       },
```

i want to use `JSON.parse();` but i get `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <`

In both cases it cannot be parsed

I dont use ajax to make request , i use a javascript engine `Rhino` like `NodeJs` and is serverside . I access the flicker public feed with a `HTTP GET` request like this (you can actually test it) :

```
https://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?format=json&lang=en-us&nojsoncallback=1
```

***THE SOLUTION*** was to add `&nojsoncallback=1` to the url so the JSON be valid

Comment: can you give us full response..

Comment: Check network tab to see if server actually returns json not html error page.

Comment: You want to go read up on what the difference between JSON and JSONP is.

Comment: Look at what's going on in `description` -- you're coming out of the string when you're not meaning to. Even the formatting here shows you the problem. You need to escape your HTML.

Comment: `" <p><a href="https://www` — Unescaped quotes in a string literal? Either you'd made an error transcribing the data or the data is arriving broken.  In the latter case, you'll need to ask the supplier of the data to fix it.

Comment: No i used javascript `replace(/\\/g, '')` to remove escaping ...

Comment: Marked as a duplicate by @Quentin - but I'm fairly sure this isn't a JSONP issue?

Comment: @thebluefox — It was before it was edited … and it still would be if the OP hadn't "used javascript .replace() to remove escaping".

Comment: @123onetwothree — Well, don't do that!

Comment: @Quentin i removed the `.replace()` part and still parsing error . I will update question with the true response from Flickr